# Storing times of a day in a single field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying to make a database for private lessons and i need to store the times of a day that the students and teachers are available. For example a teacher might be available on Mondays from 8:00-13:00 and 14:00-18:00. Is there a way i can store this data in a single field called Monday?

Comment: I'm going to guess this is schoolwork; as teachers LOVE using schools as examples for database theory. Please show us what you have done. and explain why you want to use only one field to store this data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make the field a varchar() and just put the available slots into the field as a string `8:00-13:00 and 14:00-18:00.`

I don't think this is a very good idea, because searching and sorting it, or using the data elsewhere will be practically impossible;  but if it's just being stored so it can be printed out again, that may not be an issue.

Comment: i am currently using what you have recommended i have it so letters of the alphabet symbolize unavailable hours, numbers available and the symbol + for 1 quarter / for half an hour and  - for 3 quarters. so in the example above it would be h5adf. I'm looking for more efficient and fast ways.

Comment: It's very efficient and fast to just put a string into a varchar(), I don't understand the benefit of obfuscating it. To be clear, I don't recommend that you store this information in a single field, unless you have a very good reason to do so.  You asked HOW to do it, not whether you should!